# Combine all columns into one with empty cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to combine large number of columns having similar data into one column. Rows in dataframe have a lot of empty cells as each row has its own column for this similar data. For eg:

```
Name    Weight  Addressw    Addressx    Addressy    Addressz
A       10                  11 g place  
B       15      6, corner
C       24      15, lane                garbage
D       33                                          51, street
```

In the C row, as two columns contain info, I would like to take the first one, ie "15, lane" into new column. So the resulting dataframe would look like so:

```
Name    Weight  Address
A       10      11 g place
B       15      6, corner
C       24      15, lane
D       33      51, street
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could do:

```
df['Address'] = df.lookup(np.arange(len(df)), (~df.iloc[:, 2:].isna()).idxmax(1))
result = df[['Name', 'Weight', 'Address']]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
  Name  Weight     Address
0    A      10  11 g place
1    B      15   6, corner
2    C      24    15, lane
3    D      33  51, street
```

The approach will take the first valid address from each row.

Answer (score 0):

If possible one or more addresses per rows use `join` in lambda function with remove possible missing values:

```
f = lambda x: ' '.join(y for y in x if pd.notna(y))
df = df.set_index(['Name', 'Weight']).agg(f, axis=1).reset_index(name='Address')
print (df)
  Name  Weight           Address
0    A      10        11 g place
1    B      15         6, corner
2    C      24  15, lane garbage
3    D      33        51, street
```

If exist always only one use `ffill` for forward filling missing values and selecting last column:

```
df = df.set_index(['Name', 'Weight']).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1].reset_index(name='Address')
print (df)
  Name  Weight           Address
0    A      10        11 g place
1    B      15         6, corner
2    C      24  15, lane garbage
3    D      33        51, street
```